# Set Windows file type association for a specific file only

Tags: python, windows, file-association

How do I programmatically associate a file with a specific "opens with" action? That is, I am creating `filename.py` on a Windows computer, putting it on the desktop. I want double-clicking it to run the python intrepreter, rather than opening the text editor.

I can do this with the Properties window, but I want to do this automatically, when I create it (from another python program).

I do not want to set up a universal file extension, because I want double-clicking on `.py` files to result in bringing up the editor, not running the program. It is only *for this particular file* that I want that behavior. I can do this from the Windows GUI; I want to know how to do it programmatically.

There is no installer. The Python `.py` program is being created from *another* python program. It is being created directly in the file system with a `open("filename.py").write(file_contents)`.

The environment is Windows 7

Comment: Can't you set up a universal file association, such that files with the `.py` extension open the python interpreter?

Comment: double-clicking on the .py file usually runs the program already, doesn't edit it. Unless you're using a portable version, without file associations. so ?

Comment: Please be more specific about your environment. Why can't you associate the extention with Python installer? Do you need to associate system-wide or for a specific user? Why do you need to do this programmatically rather than using the "Default Programs" in Control Panel? What tools are you planning to be making the association with -- your Python program itself or something else, perhaps written in some other language?

Comment: Before these are addressed, the question is too vague to answer so voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, I think that the question is clear. What is vague to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, file type associatons are per-extension. Any file with the same extension is treated the same. That's the whole idea behind them.

In principle, you can change the `.py` type association to run some program that would check if it runs this particular file and do a different thing.

A much easier, more manageable and predictable way to go would be to [place a shortcut](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/01/23/using-python-to-create-shortcuts/) rather than the program onto the desktop that would run anything you need -- in this case, `"path\to\python.exe" "path\to\your_program.py"`. That's the whole idea behind shortcuts btw. The file itself can be placed to some other user-writable place like `%APPDATA%\<your_project_name>` which is the standard location for application data.

Comment: I have done per-file overrides in the Windows file browser.

Comment: @vy32 if you tell me something about that, I'll probably be able to say more. My current guess is that you're confusing a regular file with a shortcut with a name like `program.py.lnk` because both Explorer and Desktop always hide the `.lnk` extension. Apart from the extension, you can recognize a shortcut by an arrow overlay icon in the corner.

Comment: Okay. Apparently I am mistaken big-time. On the Mac you can do per-file overrides, but on Windows you can only do it per extension.